# how to load the checkbox values and persist them on postback in asp.net webforms

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, checkbox

I have a bunch of check boxes and a text box which I have hard coded at this point. According to the business rule, The checkbox selection needs to get saved and also, on post back or page refresh the selection needs to persist, in my case I am able to save the values to the database, but, unable to load them again on post back. Can someone provide me a example to handle this. I think that I need to write a load method to do this. Can someone provide me with an example.

Code:

```
<div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="check">
                    <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkRS" Text="RS" />
                </div>

                <br />

                <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkSC" Text="SSC" />

                <br />

                <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="SCR" Text="SCR" />

                <br />

                <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="txtPrint">Print Button Class</asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtPrint" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            InitializeSurveys();

            if (IsPostBack) return;

            _projectContext.SelectedSurvey = null;


        }


 private void LoadSurvey(Survey survey)
        {
            ViewState["surveyId"] = survey.SurveyID;
            txtTitle.Text = survey.Name;

            chkActive.Checked = survey.Active;          

            //ddlSurveyType.SelectedValue = survey.Type;
            //TODO: There is no need for this setting
            ddlRespondentType.SelectedValue = survey.RespondentType.ToString();
            lstLanguages.Visible = false;
            lblMultipleText.Visible = false;
            lblLanguages.Visible = true;
            ddlLanguages.Enabled = false;
            lblLanguages.Text = "";
            survey.SurveyLanguages
                 .Select(s => s.Language.LanguageName)
                 .ToList().ForEach(sl => lblLanguages.Text += "<br>" + sl);
            ddlLanguages.SelectedValue = survey.DefaultLanguageID.ToString();
            txtKeywords.Text = survey.Keywords;

            ddlGroup.SelectedValue = survey.GroupId == null ? "-1" : survey.GroupId.ToString();
            lblUniqueCode.Text = $@"Code<br><div style=""border: solid 1px #ccc; background-color: #eee;padding: 7px;"">{survey.Code}</div>";

        }


protected void lnkSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var id = ViewState["surveyId"] != null
                ? long.Parse(ViewState["surveyId"].ToString())
                : 0;

            var survey = ViewState["surveyId"] != null
                ? _surveyRepo.GetSurveys().Include(s => s.ReportingGroups).Include(s => s.SurveySettings).Single(s => s.SurveyID == id)
                : new Survey();
            var ss = new List<Ss>();        

            foreach (var item in g.ss)
            {
                var setting = s.ss.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Key == item.Key);
                WebControl ctrl = GetControl(item.Key.ToString());
                if (ctrl == null) continue;
                if (setting == null)
                {
                    setting = new SurveySetting()
                    {
                        SurveyId = id,
                        Key = item.Key
                    };
                }

                if (ctrl is CheckBox)
                {
                    setting.Value = ((CheckBox)(ctrl)).Checked.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    setting.Value = ((TextBox)(ctrl)).Text;
                }

                surveySettings.Add(setting);

            }

            foreach (var temp in surveySettings)
            {
                if (!survey.SurveySettings.Any(ss => ss.Key == temp.Key))
                {
                    _surveyRepo.AddSurveySetting(temp);
                }
            }



            _sRepo.Save();


            ClearForm();

            InitializeSurveys();
            LoadDropDown();
            LoadSurveys();
            upAddUpdate.Update();
            upMain.Update();
            CloseModalOnUpdate("close_on_edit", "#NewSurveyModal");
        }
```

Comment: At a high level, you may want to differentiate between a `postback` and `initial load` of the page. On initial load, you'll want to do what you are currently doing but, on postback, you'll want to initialize your stuff differently as to keep and/or override the user entered data.

Comment: Why would it keep the values on page refresh? What if a brand new user comes to the site for the first time, what would you do in that case?

Comment: Please show us the code behind.

Comment: Thanks for the updated code. At first sight, I'd say that something in `InitializeSurveys();` is setting your checkboxes to a specific check state. And since `InitializeSurveys();` happens, before `if (IsPostBack) return;`, then checking for postBack has no effect... It has no effect because we checked for Postback *after* initializing the fields in the *non-postback* way. You could pass postback state to `InitializeSurveys(postBackState);` and then initialize your fields accordingly directly in that method.

Comment: Could you please post entire ASPX page?

Answer (score 0):

Differentiate between postback and non-postback. If you don't, depending how your page is setup, you may end up initializing the fields to their initial values on every page load, regardless of the actual postback state.

```
using System;

namespace PersistingCheckboxes_45379633
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsPostBack)
            {
                /*
                 * This is a postback, therefore I want to populate the page according to what's in the database
                 */
                txtbx_1.Text = "postback";
                chkbx_item1.Checked = WhatDoesTheDBSay(1);
                chkbx_item2.Checked = WhatDoesTheDBSay(2);
            }
            else
            {
                /*
                 * This is not a postback, so we initialize the fields
                 */
                txtbx_1.Text = "not a postback";
                chkbx_item1.Checked = false;
            }
        }

        private bool WhatDoesTheDBSay(int fieldID)
        {
            if (fieldID == 1)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Follow up to my comment about *passing postback state* to the initialization method.

```
using System;

namespace PersistingCheckboxes_45379633
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsPostBack)
            {
                //initialize taking Postback into account
                InitializeSurveys(true);
            }
            else
            {
                //initialize without postback
                InitializeSurveys(false);
            }
        }

        private void InitializeSurveys(bool IsItAPostBack)
        {
            if (IsItAPostBack)
            {
                /*
                 * This is a postback, therefore I want to populate the page according to what's in the database
                 */
                txtbx_1.Text = "postback";
                chkbx_item1.Checked = WhatDoesTheDBSay(1);
                chkbx_item2.Checked = WhatDoesTheDBSay(2);
            }
            else
            {
                /*
                 * This is not a postback, so we initialize the fields
                 */
                txtbx_1.Text = "not a postback";
                chkbx_item1.Checked = false;
            }
        }

        private bool WhatDoesTheDBSay(int fieldID)
        {
            if (fieldID == 1)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried your code but, it didn't work for my scenario